# How do I set an image background, using the <img> tag rather than CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I have created 4 columns.  Each column consisting of an image, where I want to place text over each image.

To achieve this, I obviously need to set the image as a background.  I am aware that this can be achieve through CSS (which is what I am currently doing) but I would like to place the image as a background, within my HTML file.  The reason; so that I can enter the relevant 'alt' text for SEO purposes.

How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `img` in the col container, set that element to `position: relative;` then use `absolute` positioning to put the text over the image.

```css
* {margin:0;}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your code does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#img-as-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#img-as-background .container {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#img-as-background img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-as-background">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-abstract-background_1048-1003.jpg" alt="" />
 <div class="container">
  Overflow text Overflow text Overflow text Overflow text Overflow text Overflow text Overflow text 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight Dao Minh Hat.